# Add a redux-form to a react-bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a multipage 'redux-form' form inside a react-bootstrap modal, So when you click to open the modal the form is displayed in the modal layover.

How would you go about doing that?

The following code yields an uncaught variant error:

```
class Home extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.close = this.close.bind(this)
    this.open = this.open.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    }
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false })
  }

  open() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true })
  }

    render(){
        let WizardForm = <WizardForm/>
        return(
            <Grid>
                <Row className="above">
                    <Col xs={10} md={8}><code>
                        <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={this.open}Open Form</Button>
                    </code></Col>
                </Row>

                <Row className="below">
                    <Col xs={12} md={10}><code>
                        <SlideShow/>
                    </code></Col>
                </Row>
                <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>

                    <div>{WizardForm}></div>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </Grid>
```

Edit (comps. import bit):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import SlideShow from 'containers/SlideShow'
import WizardForm from 'containers/WizardForm'
import SimpleForm from 'containers/SimpleForm'
```

When I use the simple form everything works as expected.

Comment: What is your invariant error?

Comment: Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Home`.

Comment: Could you please show the parts where you import WizardForm and the Modal. I suspect the problem is with that.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem when I use a simpleform (named export as well) it works fine. But I've added it to the edit.

Comment: So I would check that your WizardForm is exported correctly.
I have seen this before when I just `export class WizardForm extends Component {...` instead of `export default class WizardForm extends`. Doing the former would lead to the WizardForm being `undefined`.

Comment: You could also set a breakpoint in your render method and look at what you are trying to render that is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like don't have `'redux-form'` defined anywhere. You need to install it, import it, and decorate your component with it.

Per the [redux-form docs](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/getting-started?_k=hsjm0w), you should decorate your exported Modal form component in the HOC style definition.

> This will provide your component with props allowing you to attach your inputs to redux-form.

UPDATE: your code has a typo that is probably throwing an error:

`<Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={this.open}Open Form</Button>`

Should be

`<Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" onClick={this.open}>Open Form</Button>`

(missing `>`)